# JSF 2 DataTable updated through AJAX

Tags: jsf-2, datatable

Currently i have a workflow like this:

1. User enters a list of mobile numbers into a textarea.
2. User selects the option to submit the form (Non AJAX).
3. System processes the IDs, displays a JSF 2 DataTable with all mobile numbers to the user in a new page.
4. System continues to retrieve information about each mobile number sequentially (one number at a time) and updates it into the DataTable.

Currently i am not sure what i should do to achieve step 4 after displaying the DataTable at step 3.

Please kindly advise or link me to any tutorials you many have come across similar to my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options to do 4. A distinctive choice is between having the client initiate the update or having the server do this.

In the first case you'll be looking at traditional AJAX, and you could use an AJAX poll component. Both PrimeFaces and RichFaces have such a component (p:poll and a4j:poll respectively)

By default AJAX requests are serialized via a single queue, so the "one number at a time"-requirement will be automatically met. Since you only want to poll once, you should stop the poll right after receiving a result.

The other option is letting the server push the data to the client (sometimes called Reverse AJAX). In your case, when the data for the initial table with the mobile number is fetched, you'll immediately do the query for all the extra information asynchronously. As soon as the server has retrieved this info, it sends it to the data table in the client. You could do this one by one again, or if it's one query it might be more efficient to update the whole table at once.

For push, both PrimeFaces and RichFaces have components available again (p:push vs a4j:push).

See:

- http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxPollHome.jsf
- http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=poll

Comment: Hi Arjan, thanks for responding to this. The processing it does for each number includes interfacing with several external systems, and may each take some seconds to complete therefore the need to update the user on a per-number basis for better user experience. I will quickly look into your links, im using the Primefaces component library too.

Comment: Just wondering, do you think it is possible for Primefaces Push to update the datatable? It seems from the push examples that they are using JavaScript to manually handle push events.

Comment: Indeed, PrimeFaces Push doesn't seem to be in its Prime yet. Theoretically you could mix RichFaces and PrimeFaces, but since there's a poll solution you might be better off using that.